# Laravel 5.4 redirect to specific page if user is not authenticated using middleware

Tags: laravel, redirect, routes

I want to redirect user, if not authenticated, to my index page (which is the login page)

Can't seem to make it work and i really got confused with the routing.

> HomeController

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return redirect()->guest('/');
    }
}
```

> Routing

```
// Index
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'index',
    'uses' => 'UserController@index'
]);
```

> UserController

The routing as you see redirects to a **User Controller** at **index** function, which is the below :

*has **__construct()** so it uses the middleware 'auth'.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index(){

    // If user is logged
    if(Auth::check()) {

        // If user has NOT submitted information form redirect there, otherwise to categories
        if(!Auth::user()->submitted_information)
            return redirect()->route('information');
        else
            return redirect()->route('categories');
    }
    else
        return view('index', ['body_class' => 'template-home']);

}
```

> Handler.php

And the **unauthenticated function** inside middleware of auth (Exceptions/Handler.php)

```
 protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
```

The error i get right now is the below :

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 304:
Route [index] not defined.
```

This error happens because of the line of

`return redirect()->route('index');` in the above **unauthenticated** function.

What am i missing here? If you need any more information please feel free to ask.

**EDIT** : Until now, if i remove from **UserController** the `__construct()` method, and insert in `web.php` to all the routes what `middleware` to use, it works.

For example

```
Route::get('/categories', [
    'as' => 'categories',
    'uses' => 'UserController@showCategories'
])->middleware('auth');
```

But i am trying to find, without specifying there what middleware to use, to use it automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your route like below code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
     // uses 'auth' middleware
     Route::resource('blog','BlogController');
});
```

Route::get('/mypage', 'HomeController@mypage');

Open your middleware class named RedirectIfAuthenticated and then in handle fucntion
you write below code:

```
if (!Auth::check()) {
     return redirect('/mypage'); // redirect to your specific page which is public for all
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your route should be like

// Index

```
Route::get('/','UserController@index')->name('index);
```

[see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes) for more about routing.

Comment: No that didn't help..It help showing the correct routing but now there is a network loop hiting all the time the "/"

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Route::get('/','UserController@index',['middleware'=>'auth'])->name('index);
```